# How do I fix "at least one service or driver failed during system startup"?

Tags: windows-server-2003, service

Please help me what is this error? when I restart my server 2003 was error " at least one service or driver failed during system startup. Use event viewer to examine the event log for details." anyone can help me please.

Comment: To find the event log right click on My Computer and select Manage or go to Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Computer Management.
[**This**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175653) may help you track down the events your looking for

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to say this without sounding flippant, but the error message is telling you what to do.

The first place you should be going, on a Windows NT-based operating system (like W2K3), when you're sorting out misbehavior with the OS is the event log. Doubly so when the error message tells you to do that.

Some service or driver program marked for automatic startup on boot is failing to start properly. The service control manager (responsible for invoking these programs) will make a record in the event log as to the details of the failure and, from there, you can work on resolving the error.

Comment: +1 for putting it more elegantly that I probably would have.

Answer (score 1):

As Evan and Iain have stated, you need to check the System event log on the server to see what service (or device) is not starting. You can also check the Services control panel applet to check for any Automatic startup services that haven't started. If you're unable to find anything there then check device manager and view hidden devices and look for any devices with a yellow exclamation point or red X through them. These are often file system drivers or "soft" network device drivers that haven't started for some reason, possibly due to their host software being uninstalled). If you're running Enterprise edition this error will occur for the NLB service if NLB is not configured, if this is the case this message can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can occur if a service or driver does not start correctly.

Please first test the problem in Safe Mode with Networking.

Meanwhile, please open Device Manager and show Hidden devices. Check if there is yellow exclamation mark. If so, disable this service temporarily and reboot to test the problem.

For further research, please collect MPS report on the problematic computer:

1. Download proper MPS Report tool from the website below.

Microsoft Product Support Reports

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=CEBF3C7C-7CA5-408F-88B7-F9C79B7306C0&displaylang=en

2. Double-click to run it, if requirement is not met, please follow the wizard to download and install them. After that, click Next, when the "Select the diagnostics you want to run" page appears, select "General", , click Next.
3. After collecting all log files, choose "Save the results", choose a folder to save MPSReports.cab file. Please use Windows Live SkyDrive (http://www.skydrive.live.com/) to upload the file and then give us the download address.